# non greedy grep command on ubuntu?

Tags: linux, grep, regular-expressions

I'm building a script which filters out all our translatables from our template system.
the problem i'm facing is the occasion where 2 translatables are on one line.

These are 2 example lines from a template file which both hold one or more translatables

```
<img src="/captcha/generate.jpg" alt="[#Captcha#]" />
<span>[#Velden met een * zijn verplicht in te vullen#]</span> <button type="submit" name="frm_submit" class="right">[#Verzend#]
```

And when i set loose the following regexp

```
egrep "\[#(.*)#\]" . -Rohis
```

I get this output

```
[#Captcha#]"
[#Velden met een * zijn verplicht in te vullen#]</span> <button type="submit" name="frm_submit" class="right">[#Verzend#]
```

While the desired output is

```
[#Captcha#]
[#Velden met een * zijn verplicht in te vullen#]
[#Verzend#]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agree with Kyle.  However, in this case, you could do this: `egrep "\[#([^]])*)#\]" . -Rohis` and get what you're looking for.

The `[^]]*` matches non-`]` characters, so it'll stop at the first `]` it hits.

Comment: on the side note, this trick (in 2nd paragraph) works here but is not solution to general problem, it fails here `[#Verze]nd#]`

Answer (score 2):

Trying to parse HTML with regular expressions leads to pain, just don't do it.  Jeff wrote about it in [Parsing Html The Cthulhu Way](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001311.html).  "But I only want to ______", doesn't matter, seriously, don't do it.  Take a little time and learn something designed to parse html.

I personally would recommend a Perl Module for this (such as [HTML::TreeBuilder](http://search.cpan.org/~petek/HTML-Tree-3.23/lib/HTML/TreeBuilder.pm)), but what languages do you know? Other options are: tidy+ xmlstarlet xmlgawk xpath xml2.

If you just want the "rendered" html in text, you can use something like links: `links -dump www.google.com`

Comment: I'm not trying to parse HTML, i'm trying to compile a list of all translation strings used in our framework, wether they are in a html, tpl, txt, csv or php file doesn't mater, nor does the context.

Comment: Ah, well the negated character class is the general way to get non-greedy like operations as others stated.

Answer (score 1):

Seconded Kyle comment.

Anyway, if the pattern is sufficiently uniform, you can achieve what you want my matching anything but the closing character, i.e.

```
egrep "\[#([^]]*)#\]" ...
```

This pattern will not work if you have closing ] inside the text, e.g. [#xyz]#] will not match.

Answer (score 0):

Use Perl, which lets you do non-greedy matches.  For your case where you watch multiple matches, do it like with the /g modifier.  We add the -l switch because we have to handle linefeeds ourselves:

```
perl -lne'while(/\[#(.*?)#\]/g) {print $&}' filename
```